# Convert list with one item (map) to map

Tags: elixir

How would you convert `[%{"hello" => 123}]` to just `%{"hello" => 123}`?

I could `Enum.at(map, 0)` but doesnt look good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use pattern matching:

```
iex(1)> [map] = [%{"hello" => 123}]
iex(2)> map
# => %{"hello" => 123}
```

or

```
iex(1)> [%{"hello" => value} = map] = [%{"hello" => 123}]
iex(2)> map
# => %{"hello" => 123}
iex(3)> value
# => 123
```

if you need the value for the `"hello"` key.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by @guitarman is perfectly correct, there is also [`Kernel.hd/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#hd/1) than takes the head of the list:

```
iex> [%{"hello" => 123}] |> hd()
%{"hello" => 123}
```

The difference is pattern matching to the one-element-list (`[map] =`) would raise `MatchError` on an empty list (the above raises `ArgumentError`,) and the latter will successfully return a value when the list has more than one element.